# Method to return a file or a view

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using the jquery below to call a `GetFile` method. 
I want to generate a text file based on some conditions. This will not always
generate a text file all the time.

If condition = True generate the file

If condition = False return back to the main page

Right now if i do return, I just get a blank page.

How can I write this such that my two conditions are considered?

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            var SelCat = $("#mylist").val();              
            if (SelCat != 0) {
                var data = {
                    categoryId: SelCat   
                }
                var url = '@Url.Action("GetFile", "Home")' + '?' + $.param(data);
                window.location.assign(url);
            } else {
                alert("You need to select an city");
            }
        });
    });   
</script>
```

```c#
public void GetFile(int categoryId)
{
    var fileName = "ErrorMessages.txt";
    StringBuilder strObj = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 20000; i++)
    {
        strObj.Append("Number:" + i + " " + "Here is the first line" );
        strObj.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    strObj.ToString();

    // ...
    // Based on some conditions determine whether to return a file or not
    // return;

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + fileName );
    Response.Write(strObj);
    //Response.BinaryWrite(strObj);

    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Is `GetFile` a controller action? I'm guessing not, as it is returning `void`.

Comment: GetFile resides in a controller but not an ActionResult

Comment: It needs to be an Action for it to be accessible.

Comment: Right now the code works very well. I just had a problem with what to pass if I don't want to generate a file. I don't know what you mean by accessible.

Comment: " _right now the code works very well._ " So well that you're posting on SO for help?

Comment: Why are you writing directly to `Response`? This barely qualifies as MVC.

Comment: No joke, you really need to return an ActionResult from an action method of some sort.  Maybe you're looking for the Controller.File method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO:

1. Change your `GetFile` to be an `ActionResult`.
2. If the file can be written
   a. Writing to a memory stream (instead of response)
   b. `return File(memoryStream, "text/plain");`
3. If it can't be written
   a. `return Redirect("~/Main/Page");`

Pseudo code:

```
public ActionResult GetFile(Int32 CategoryId)
{
  if (/*can be written*/)
  {
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
      using (StreamWriter writer new StreamWriter(stream))
      {
        /* writer.Write(...); */
      }
      return File(stream, "text/plain");
    }
  }
  return Redirect("~/main/Page"); // or redirectToRoute/RedirectToAction
}
```

And for reference: [`File()` response methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

*FWIW: You can continue to use the `StringBuilder` and pass that to one of the `File()` overloads, I guess I just prefer streams. :shrug:*